# Windows 10 install very slow on Mid 2012 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I made a Win10 USB installer using the media creation tool on my PC and I have a SSD in a drive caddy which replaced my DVD drive.

I want to clean install Win10 to this SSD but the Win10 installer takes hours - no joke - to boot up and then it takes forever to start the setup.

I already installed it before but when booting from the disk after install it just ends in a boot loop. The USB drive should be working fine I don't think it's the problem. And the SSD in the caddy also works fine.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can install Win10?

Answer (score 1):

It had something to do with the problem I solved here:   [HGST 1tb in mid 2012 mbpro not working in sata bay but drive seems fine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278508/hgst-1tb-in-mid-2012-mbpro-not-working-in-sata-bay-but-drive-seems-fine).  After I solved that issue, the Windows install worked normally again