# HGST 1TB in Mid 2012 MacBook Pro not working in SATA bay but drive seems fine

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, hdd, sata

In my Mid-2012 13 inch MacBook Pro I have a 500GB HDD in the standard SATA bay and I replaced the DVD drive with a drive cage which has a SSD in it. I bought this [Hitachi HST 1TB drive](https://www.amazon.de/Travelstar-7K1000-interne-Festplatte-7200rpm/dp/B00B4QESVQ/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1491242102&sr=8-13&keywords=1tb%202%2C5) \to replace my 500GB drive, but when I put it in the standard SATA bay I can't format it and I couldn't install Windows or Linux on it.

I took it out again and I connected it with a SATA to USB cable and it worked perfectly, so the drive is not broken, I suspected the data cable is broken because that happens sometimes with this model MacBook Pro.  I put the old 500GB drive back in, and it works fine. So it can't be the cable, this doesn't really make sense to me but I'm going to try to put the 1TB drive into the drive cage and the SSD into the standard drive bay.

Any ideas or suggestions what I should try?

Answer (score 2):

Solution: So I swapped the drives, put the 1tb HDD into the cage and the ssd into the standard drive bay. I don't understand why exactly but it works :)